# Branch on null vs null object performance

Tags: c++, dispatch, branch-prediction, null-object-pattern

Which is most efficient: using a null object, or a branch on nullptr. Example in C++:

```cpp
void (*callback)() = [](){}; // Could be a class member

void doDoStuff()
    {
    // Some code
    callback();  // Always OK. Defaults to nop
    // More code
    }
```

vs

```cpp
void (*callback)() = nullptr; // Could be a class member

void doDoStuff()
    {
    // Some code
    if(callback != nullptr)  // Check if we should do something or not
        {callback();}
    // More code
    }
```

The null object will always do an indirect function call, assuming the compiler cannot inline it. Using a nullptr, will always do branch, and if there is something to do, it will also do an indirect function call.

Would replacing callback with a pointer to an abstract base class affect the decision?

What about the likelihood of `callback` set to something other than nullptr. I guess that if `callback` is most likely nullptr, then it is faster with the additional branch, right?

Comment: The answer is: benchmark.

Comment: I'm not sure this question has an answer unless you specify what hardware the code is running on, since various pieces of hardware will have varying performance characteristics.

Comment: Not to mention the interactions with the various code *around* that call. Basically, you cannot know things like this a priori. This is why micro-optimizations should be avoided until you have specific code to test and ***certain knowledge*** that this code is a performance problem.

Comment: When you do your profiling, make sure you are using an optimized build.  A non-optimized build is not useful for profiling.

Comment: Having the condition makes the cost of applying good callbacks slightly higher. Having the null callback, especially if it is at a nearby address to the calling code would only be slightly slower than taking the conditional shortcut. So it all depends how often your callback is good. If your callback is good more than 50% of the time, then probably go with the callback, but the only answer is to profile ALL your code and discover whether this is REALLY the bottleneck that is worth stressing over AT ALL, or you should just implement whichever is the more convenient solution.

Comment: Unless you have a *measurable performance problem* the best plan is to not concern yourself with this sort of optimization. If this is happening so many times it's causing a decrease in frames-per-second or transactions-per-minute, then sure, you could benchmark to find out, but honestly this sort of trivialism is completely, utterly irrelevant unless it's being called *millions of times per second* on a regular basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which is most efficient: using a null object, or a branch on nullptr.

Assuming a given codegen solution, it will depend on your target. And, if you don't assume that, it will also depend on your code, compiler and probably moon phase.

> Would replacing callback with a pointer to an abstract base class affect the decision?

In most scenarios that will end up being also dynamic dispatch.

> What about the likelihood of callback set to something other than nullptr. I guess that if callback is most likely nullptr, then it is faster with the additional branch, right?

That would depend on the ratio and also on the hardware (whether a branch is faster or not compared to a indirect function call; which also depends on the ratio).

---

Just to make you aware of how subtle things are: let's assume you are talking about modern x86_64 desktop processors with the call not being inlined and with a likelihood of 99% of the time being `nullptr`. People told you to measure.

So you did and, in this case, let's assume you found out the branch seems faster. Great! So we should start using branches everywhere, right?

Not really, because your branch predictor will have likely made the code effectively free (branch never taken), which means you were not even comparing branches vs. indirect calls at all.

Comment: But surely, this is the best possible answer? <<Not much, because your branch predictor will probably make the branch free, which means you will never be measuring indirect calls vs. branches.>>

Answer (score 3):

None of these questions can be answer a priori. They will depend on a myriad of factors, including but not limited to, the specifics of the hardware, the specifics of the cache at the time of the call, the various code around such a call which may hide any latencies introduced, the quality of the compiler's inlining/devirtualization power (which again, depends on the specific details of all the code) and so forth.

Micro-optimizations of this sort should only be attempted when you have the exact code you intend to optimize, as well as *certain knowledge* that the code in question is a performance problem worthy of such optimization.

Answer (score 2):

## You have to test the code and find out

There's simply no way to know for certain whether this code is faster or slower without testing it—and the results of that test might not be applicable to your specific application or environment, even if the test has the same compiler and target as your build.

Compilers are very good at optimizing code, especially with respect to behavior that is semi-predictable, and CPUs are often built with Branch Prediction or other similar technologies that reduce the costs of having to branch code. So the answer depends pretty exclusively on the specific use-case of your code, the target device for your code, and the conditions under which it's operating.